# rrule: Using TZID without Luxon available is unsupported

Tags: node.js, rrule, luxon

I have a very simple project, using the `rrule` package:

```
npm init -f
npm i rrule
```

`index.js` file:

```
import { RRule, RRuleSet, rrulestr } from 'rrule';

const rule = RRule.fromString(
  "DTSTART;TZID=America/Denver:20181101T190000;\n"
  + "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE,TH;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=3"
)
rule.all();
```

Yet this gives the following message, three times:

```
Using TZID without Luxon available is unsupported. Returned times are in UTC, not the requested time zone
```

Why doesn't this work? I can see `luxon` is in the dependencies of the `node_modules/luxon` package. I've tried installing `luxon` into my own package too (`npm i luxon`), but with no success. What am I missing?

Comment: I solved this with `yarn upgrade rrule` to upgrade my `rrule` node_module to the newest version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the [issue](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule/issues/427) started with version 2.6.6. A temporary solution would be to install a version that works.
I did `npm i rrule@2.6.4`.

Comment: Looks correct to me, although I solved this by using [`(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset`). I don't have the code to hand ,but once I do, I'll tack that on as a comment, for those who might be tied into a version